Excel to DXF dimension text enlargement
I've been working on a project in Excel for quite some time to make some calculations easier. I also came up with the idea to generate a preliminary drawing via a DXF file instead of importing the results into BricsCAD using coordinates. I'm having trouble enlarging the dimension text and arrowheads. As you can see, I've scaled the text, but that’s the wrong method since it creates issues during later editing. I’ve tried using code 40 and various other methods. Code 40 works for regular text but not for dimension text. I’m worried I may have broken something else in the file. Does anyone know how to fix this? The code includes what I need and works, including rounding to 5cm or to one decimal place and indicating negative values. However, I can’t figure out how to change the size of the dimension text or the arrowheads. I also tried shifting the dimension text, but I can only move it sideways, not upwards for some reason.

Sub DodajWymiarowanie(fileNumber As Integer)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim firstDataRow As Long
    Dim wymiar As String
    Dim odleglosc As Double
    Dim roznicaY As Double

    ' Znajdź pierwszy i ostatni wiersz z danymi w kolumnie B i C
    firstDataRow = 13 ' Ustalenie startu od wiersza 13
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Ostatni wiersz z danymi w kolumnie B

    ' Dodanie wymiarowania liniowego w pliku DXF
    For i = firstDataRow To lastRow
        ' Sprawdzenie, czy są dane w kolumnach B, C oraz I, J, oraz pomijanie pierwszego i ostatniego wiersza
        If i <> firstDataRow And i <> lastRow Then
            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 2).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 3).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 9).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 10).Value) Then
                ' Oblicz odległość między punktami
                odleglosc = Sqr((Cells(i, 9).Value - Cells(i, 2).Value) ^ 2 + (Cells(i, 10).Value - Cells(i, 3).Value) ^ 2)

                ' Obliczenie różnicy między wartościami Y z kolumny C i J
                roznicaY = Cells(i, 3).Value - Cells(i, 10).Value

                ' Zaokrąglenie odległości do najbliższych 5 cm i dodanie minusa lub plusa w zależności od różnicy
                If roznicaY < -0.024999 Then
                    wymiar = "-" & FormatZaokraglenieDo5cm(odleglosc) & "m" ' Dodanie minusa, jeśli różnica jest ujemna
                Else
                    wymiar = FormatZaokraglenieDo5cm(odleglosc) & "m" ' Standardowy wymiar, jeśli różnica jest dodatnia
                End If

                ' Dodaj wymiarowanie pomiędzy punktami
                Print #fileNumber, "0"
                Print #fileNumber, "DIMENSION"
                Print #fileNumber, "8"
                Print #fileNumber, "WYMIAROWANIE"
                
                ' Ustawienie koloru na niebieski (DXF color code 5)
                Print #fileNumber, "62"
                Print #fileNumber, "5" ' Kod koloru dla niebieskiego
                
                Print #fileNumber, "100"
                Print #fileNumber, "AcDbAlignedDimension"
                
                ' Środkowy punkt wymiarowania (gdzie pojawi się tekst wymiarowy)
                Print #fileNumber, "10" ' Punkt wymiarowy X
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format((Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value) / 2, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "20" ' Punkt wymiarowy Y
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format((Cells(i, 3).Value + Cells(i, 10).Value) / 2, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "30" ' Współrzędna Z
                Print #fileNumber, "0.0"
                
                ' Dodaj wartość wymiaru z powiększeniem
                Print #fileNumber, "1" ' Tekst wymiarowy
                Print #fileNumber, "\H11.1111111111x;" & wymiar ' Dodanie wymiaru po zaokrągleniu i powiększenia
                
                ' Punkty bazowe (Początkowy i końcowy punkt wymiarowania)
                Print #fileNumber, "13" ' Punkt początkowy X
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format(Cells(i, 2).Value, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "23" ' Punkt początkowy Y
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format(Cells(i, 3).Value, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "33"
                Print #fileNumber, "0.0" ' Z

                Print #fileNumber, "14" ' Punkt końcowy X
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format(Cells(i, 9).Value, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "24" ' Punkt końcowy Y
                Print #fileNumber, Replace(Format(Cells(i, 10).Value, "0.000"), ",", ".")
                Print #fileNumber, "34"
                Print #fileNumber, "0.0" ' Z
                
                ' Wartość wymiaru
                Print #fileNumber, "50" ' Kąt wymiarowania
                Print #fileNumber, "0.0"

                ' Wymiarowanie wyśrodkowane
                Print #fileNumber, "70" ' Flaga wymiarowania (aligned)
                Print #fileNumber, "1" ' Aligned dimension
                
                ' Zakończ wymiarowanie
                Print #fileNumber, "0"
                Print #fileNumber, "SEQEND"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function FormatZaokraglenieDo5cm(wartosc As Double) As String
    ' Zaokrąglanie wartości do najbliższych 5 cm (0.05 metra)
    Dim zaokraglonaWartosc As Double
    zaokraglonaWartosc = Round(wartosc * 20, 0) / 20

    ' Sprawdzenie, czy liczba kończy się na .05 lub .15 (itd.) - wtedy pokazujemy dwa miejsca po przecinku
    If zaokraglonaWartosc * 100 Mod 10 = 5 Then
        FormatZaokraglenieDo5cm = Format(zaokraglonaWartosc, "0.00") ' Dwa miejsca po przecinku
    Else
        ' W przeciwnym wypadku pokazujemy jedno miejsce po przecinku
        FormatZaokraglenieDo5cm = Format(zaokraglonaWartosc, "0.0")
    End If
End Function

Print #fileNumber, "\H11.1111111111x;"` ' It works, but it's not the proper method for further text processing.

' Ustawienie wysokości tekstu dla każdego wymiaru
Print #fileNumber, "40"
Print #fileNumber, "4.0" ' Wysokość tekstu ustawiona na 4 jednostki` -  doesn't work

Const DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE As Double = 2.0

Print #fileNumber, "9"
Print #fileNumber, "$DIMTXT"
Print #fileNumber, "40"
Print #fileNumber, "2.0"


The topic can be closed. The errors were caused by other elements of my code. You helped me a bit by confirming that it was fine, and I also got some help on another forum. I started experimenting, and it worked out. I added a table for dimensioning, removed duplicate entries, and it worked.
